# How to fit the map inside the div container removing white spaces Mapbox

Tags: css, angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using `mapbox-js` API for a web app, but I couldn't figure out how to fit the map, avoid draggable, and appear a white frame at the top and bottom.

[image: normal]

[image: white-top]

[image: white-bottom]

I have been trying with multiple solutions, the first, was the normal way that using, but that's not my case, due my map is a child component into the father component

#### Child component

```
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 ml-0">
      <b>Needs to know:</b>
      <span class="text-primary ml-3">
        <b>4
          <span class="material-icons check-icon-position mr-1">
            check_circle_outline
          </span>
        </b>
      </span>
      |
      <span class="text-danger ml-2">
        <b>2 ETA Delay</b>
      </span>

    </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-row justify-content-end align-items-start">
      <p class="text-muted">Style map:</p>
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check ml-3" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>
      <label class="btn btn-light ml-3 btn-style-position text-muted" for="option1" (click)="setGrayStyle()"><b>Gray</b></label>

      <input type="radio" class="btn-check ml-3" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
      <label class="btn btn-light ml-3 btn-style-position text-muted" for="option2" (click)="setDarkStyle()"><b>Dark</b></label>

      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off">
      <label class="btn btn-light ml-3 btn-style-position text-muted" for="option4" (click)="setColorStyle()"><b>Color</b></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map-container" class="col-12">
  <div #miniMapa class="mapa-acordeon border-rnd-map"></div>
</div>
```

#### Father component

```
<details>
  <summary class="bg-light text-dark">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light
                bg-light fs-3 justify-content-end"
                (click)="changeMapArrow()">
      <span class="material-icons">
        <b>{{arrowClass}}</b>
      </span>
    </nav>
  </summary>
  <div class="row d-flex flex-column">
    <app-mini-map></app-mini-map>
  </div>
</details>
```

I had been used to this

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
```

I found this in one answer, but doesn't work

```
<div id="map-container">
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</div>

#map-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 180px;
    width: 600px;
}

#map {
    position: relative;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```

Even if I remove the CSS about position and things that maybe could cause any issue, still happens

[image: canvas1]

[image: canvas2]

[image: canvas3]

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use this:**

```
<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px" >

var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:50, lng:5},
  zoom: 4,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
```

Comment: I don't know, I don't follow you, can you explain what is the container o the div with the map?